# How can I remove Structure Data from my content

Tags: seo, com-content, microdata

i like to remove the structure data from my content. How can I do that?

for example:

```
itemprop="headline"
itemprop="articleBody"
```

[image]

Comment: The structured data is there for SEO purposes, what is your reason for wanting to remove it? If you haven't installed any plugins or custom code to add this it is likely part of your template. Can you provide a link to your site or advise what template you are using?

Comment: If an answer provides a solution to your problem it's good etiquette, and good manners, to mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

That markup is in your templates layout layout overrides, e.g. `/templates/YOUR-TEMPLATE/html/com_content/article/default.php` if you have one, if not it's coming from the core com_content view. The best option is to [create an override](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:How_to_use_the_Template_Manager#Creating_Overrides) yourself and alter the markup as you see fit.